# Export UnityProject inside Android Studio's existing project

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I am new to the Unity3D, but I have made a small Unity project with a humanoid `gameobject`. I can move this humanoid with the demo data but I want to move it with the quaternion data which I am already getting inside the android app.

I have searched on the internet, but everyone just tells about the android plugin that we have to make for the unity, and that way we can use the JNI to send or receive the data (I need to access the c# scripts from the android).

But, I wanted to import the unity project inside the android project so that I can(access the c# scripts from android and send the quaternion data to the Quaternion variable of the `gameObject` and make it move) make changes to the android app and test it instantly!! (Also I don't need to make further changes inside the unity project but I need to make further improvements to the data inside the android project).

Please help and provide a guide for the android studio.
Thanks.